# Sorting an array of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create a function that sorts a function and calls it. The problem is that each function may have a different number of arguments, and these arguments must be passed before the sorting. For example:

```
function sortFunciton(arrayOfFunctions) {

}

mySortedFunction = sortFunction([function1('a', 'b'), function2('a'), function3('a','b','c')])
```

The problem is that if I pass the array like this, I'll be passing the value of the function already, but I don't want these functions to be executed before the sorting, because they have heavy computation, so just one must be executed, which is why I'm sorting.

Isn't there a way to pass like this:

```
mySortedFunction = sortFunction([function1.args('a', 'b', 'c')], function2.args('a'), function3.args('a', 'b', 'c')])
```

and then do

```
mysortedFunction.callWithArgs()
```

?

Comment: `function.prototype.bind` may help

Comment: You cannot compare functions, so I don't know how you would sort them? What exactly do you mean by "*so just one must be executed, which is why I'm sorting*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the uninvoked function reference with certain bound arguments by using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
function selectFunc(funcArray) {
  //some selection criteria
  return funcArray[0];
}

mySelectedFunc = selectFunc([function1.bind(null, 'a', 'b'), function2.bind(null, 'a'), function3.bind(null, 'a','b','c')]);

mySelectedFunc() //equivalent of running function1('a', 'b')
```

Comment: then I just call mySortedFunction()?

Comment: following this pattern allows you to haven an array of functions, not an array of the results of the functions. what should `sortFunction` do?

Comment: It must select one of these functions to be invoked with these arguments.

Comment: ah gotcha - so yea you could just call `mySortedFunction()` - will update answer

Comment: @Gatonito, hackerrdave, binding `this` is fast as ****. Using `bind()` to partially apply a function *(what you show)* is way slower than a closure *(in modern JS-engines)*. I'd recommend implementing the functions as higher order functions in the first place: instead of `function fn1(arg1, arg2, a, b){ return a-b }` and binding `arg1` and `arg2`, `function fn1(arg1, arg2){ return function(a, b){ return a-b} }` and calling it as `var sortFn = fn1("foo", "bar");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) then just call your function without arguments (it will be called with the parameters that have been bound)

```js
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
function mult(a, b) { return a * b; }
var functions = [add.bind(this, 1, 1), mult.bind(this, 5, 5)];

functions.forEach(f => console.log(f()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortFunciton(arrayOfFunctions) {

}

var mySortedFunction = sortFunction([
    { func: function1, arguments: ['a', 'b']}, 
    { func: function2, arguments: ['a']}, 
    { func: function3, arguments: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
]);

for (var i = 0; i < mySortedFunction.length; i++)
{
    mySortedFunction[i].func.apply(this, mySortedFunction[i].arguments);
};
```